# Segfault when importing Swift enumeration with String.Index associated value from framework

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm experimenting with Swift frameworks. I've discovered some strange behavior. Look at the  following enumeration from my framework:

```
public enum Sobchak {
    case Walter(String.Index)
}
```

In my framework, this compiles without a problem. Unit tests using it work fine. But if I create another project, reference my framework, and then create a declaration using the enumeration above, the compiler actually crashes with a segmentation fault. (It also kills SourceKitService completely.) The problem appears to be related to `String.Index` (which is actually a `struct`, not a type alias). If I take it out, everything works. If I use a simple type like `Int` or `String`, no problem. I can even use type aliases, e.g.:

```
public enum Sobchack {
    case Walter(Array<Int>.Element)
}
```

This compiles just fine. (Of course, anyone saying `Array<Int>.Element` instead of just `Int` should be quietly shown the door.)

Anyone have any insight on this? `String.Index` is definitely the culprit. I can't reproduce this problem with any other type.